# How to enter normal mode while in terminal buffer?

Tags: terminal, normal-mode

Recently I found out that vim has added the :terminal command which opens a terminal buffer within vim, however I see no way to enter normal mode so that I can move around and copy things. Neovim has it as \n. Is there an equivalent in vim which lets me switch to normal mode?

Comment: See the help `:h terminal-use`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Ctrl-W N`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#t_CTRL-W_N) to enter normal mode from the terminal. (That's `Ctrl-W Shift+N`, for an uppercase `N`).

It is also possible to use `Ctrl-\ Ctrl-N`, which might be easier to type (thanks @D.BenKnoble for the comment.)

Thanks @ChristianBrabandt for the tip on [`:help terminal-use`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-use).

Comment: Also `<C-\><C-n>`, which i find easier to type.